# Matcher not returning correct group number

Tags: java, regex

[via](https://regex101.com/) I tested my regex

```
([\S]*)[\[]([\d]+)[-]([\d]+)[\]]
```

but when I'm using it in Java, it doesn't return to me last found group.

Ex: value - **index[1-9]**

via regex101 - it returns me "index", "1", "9"

but in Java -"index" and "1" only

Here the piece of code I'm using:

```
String regex = "([\\S]*)[\\[]([\\d]+)[-]([\\d]+)[\\]]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if(matcher.find()){
 for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++)
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
}
```

Any clues, why this happens?

Comment: Please show how you defined the regex in Java code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ([\S]*)[\[]([\d]+)[-]([\d]+)([\]])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `matcher.group(int)`, capture group numbers start at 1, not 0. From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-):

> Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression `m.group(0)` is equivalent to `m.group()`.

Comment: Actually, there is a 0th group, it is the whole match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Yeah. Thanks for pointing that out. I was just adding in the appropriate excerpt from the docs. To be technically correct, I revised my answer to say specifically "capture group numbers".

Comment: I learned something new today. Granted I don't do a lot of regex in Java. Thanks.